# for a unique column value find multiple distinct values with duplicates removed

Tags: oracle

I think title might be confusing so I'll explain it here. Sorry about that. 
Explaining it below -

```
Table A -
USERID 
1
2
3
4
5

Table B -
User ID     City
1           New York
1           New York
1           New Delhi
2           Boston
2           Dallas 
2           Boston
3           Las Vegas
4           Bombay
5           Hong Kong
```

So I need query which will result User IDs and distinct City values for it without the duplicates and have more than 1 City.

Result Set -

```
UserID   City
1        New York
1        New Delhi
2        Boston
2        Dallas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, using analytic functions (so that the data only needs to be processed once):

```
with
  table_b ( user_id, city ) as (
    select 1, 'New York'  from dual union all
    select 1, 'New York'  from dual union all
    select 1, 'New Delhi' from dual union all
    select 2, 'Boston'    from dual union all
    select 2, 'Dallas'    from dual union all
    select 2, 'Boston'    from dual union all
    select 3, 'Las Vegas' from dual union all
    select 4, 'Bombay'    from dual union all
    select 4, 'Bombay'    from dual union all
    select 5, 'Hong Kong' from dual
  )
select user_id, city
from
       (
         select user_id, city,
                count(distinct city) over (partition by user_id) as cnt,
                row_number() over (partition by user_id, city order by null) as rn
         from   table_b
       )
where  cnt > 1 and rn = 1
;

   USER_ID CITY    
---------- ---------
         1 New Delhi
         1 New York 
         2 Boston   
         2 Dallas
```

Comment: That works and pretty sophisticated way to go about it. I wrote a mile long query for it.
Though that was just a sample, practically I'm working on huge Data here, and need to join many more tables together. But this is the way to go. Thanks, Big help.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Select 
    x.*
From (
    Select
        x.*,
        count() over(partition by x.userid) cnt
    From (
        Select distinct
            a.userid,
            b.city 
        From 
            tablea a
            inner join tableb b on b.userid = a.userid
    ) x
) x
Where
    x.cnt >= 2
```

Comment: The poster wants to return rows only for those UserID's that have AT LEAST TWO distinct cities. Your solution doesn't do that.

Comment: My mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SQL> with test (user_id, city) as
  2    (select 1, 'new york' from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'new york' from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'new delhi' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'boston' from dual union all
  6     select 2, 'dallas' from dual union all
  7     select 2, 'boston' from dual union all
  8     select 3, 'las vegas' from dual union all
  9     select 4, 'bombay' from dual union all
 10     select 5, 'hong kong' from dual
 11    )
 12  select distinct user_id, city
 13  from test
 14  where user_id in (select user_id
 15                    from test
 16                    group by user_id
 17                    having count(distinct city) > 1
 18                   );

   USER_ID CITY
---------- ---------
         1 new york
         1 new delhi
         2 boston
         2 dallas

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below works:

```
 select distinct * from test t2
 where 
 exists (
    select 1 from test t1 
   where t1.UserID=t2.UserID
   having count(distinct t1.City) > 1
 )
```